# How can I create a line after my text to the width of the container?

Tags: css, class, html, underline

Yes, I'm a newb so please go easy.  I know there's got to be several ways to accomplish this.  Basically I've been trying to come up with a consistent way to have a header with a line after the text that will run to the full width of a container element.

Something like this:

```
This is my header _______________________________________________________ |<- end container
This is another header __________________________________________________ |<- end container
```

I'm trying to create a .line class that will use bottom-border to create the line but I've been unsuccessful at creating a variable length line that will extend the full width of the container.

Here's what I've tried:

CSS:

```
.line
{
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:2px #5B3400 solid;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:80%;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <h2>Our Mission<span class="line"></span></h2>
```

Of course this only gives me a line 80% of the container from the left border including the width of the text.  How can I create a line that begins after the text and runs the full width of the border regardless of how much text is on the same line?

I know this should be easy but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry wintercounter I'm new to the site so it won't let me bump up two solutions! :(

Also, under Axel's solution I added the comment that I'm using a textured background.  I think this has put me on the right track I'll just need to figure out the background issue now.

Thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**THIS METHOD WILL WORK WITH TEXTURED BACKGROUNDS (background images):**

You can try using this method instead, if your `<h2>` is on top of a background image.

**HTML:**

```
<h2 class="line-title"><span>This is my title</span><hr /></h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
.line-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 1px; /* Allows for hr margin to start at top of h2 */
}

/* clearfix for floats */
.line-title:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.line-title span {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.line-title hr {
    border:1px solid #DDD;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yYBDD/1/

**How it Works:**

1. the `<h2>` tag acts as a container for a floated element.
2. the `<span>` is floated left, causing the `<hr />` to collapse to the left and fill the right space.
3. the `<hr />` acts as the line, and fills up the remaining space to the right.

Comment: That's it!  Perfect, thanks Axel!  I changed the line to match my font colour and adjusted the .line-title hr {margin-top} to 27px to put the line right at the bottom of the font (my font size is 28px) but otherwise this is EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

**THIS METHOD WILL WORK WITH SOLID BACKGROUND COLORS:**

**HTML:**

```
<h2 class="line-title"><span>This is my title</span></h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
.line-title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.line-title span {
    background: #FFF;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yYBDD/

**How it works.**

1. the `<h2>` tag has a class that sets the height to half of the height of the text it contains.
2. the `<h2>` has a bottom border, that extends to the width of it's parent container (since it's a block element).
3. the `<span>` inside of the `<h2>` has a white background, which will cover the area where the text and border overlap.
4. And finally, the `<h2>`> has a bottom margin, that compensates for the reduced height of the `<h2>`.

Comment: thx for this. I do prefer to be able to use a class since it provides a bit more flexibility. This *would* be the perfect solution, unfortunately my page has a textured background.  Would I just need to set the background attribute to my texture in this case?

Comment: @user2092975 If you have a texture, there's a good chance it won't line up properly.  This method will only work with a solid background.

Comment: @user2092975 - I've added another answer, which uses a different technique that should work with textured background images.  Check it out ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use flexbox to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/eHHep/ (prefixes not included)

```
<h1 class="lineme">This is my header</h1>

<h2 class="lineme">This is another header</h2>

.lineme {
    display: flex;
}

.lineme:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Advantages over other methods:

- No extra markup required
- Background color is not required

Down side:

- Support for flexbox is low due to IE10 being the first IE to support it (see http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)
- Your line goes away if your text wraps around

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<h2><span>Our Mission</span></h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

h2 span{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    height: 21px;
}
```

This way it'll overflow on the bottom border as it has bigger height.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afuzk/

Comment: good solution thx! both you and Axel are on the same wavelength!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I tried and that worked:

**HTML**

```
<h2>Our Mission</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2:after
{
    content:       "\00a0";
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
    position:      fixed;
    top:           0;
    width:         100%;
    margin-left:   3px;
}
```

The JS Bin to test: http://jsbin.com/ayuvuc/4

Comment: thx that looked great in your test but didn't work for me. i'm on css 2.1 and trying to maintain compatibility with some older browsers - is 'display:box' a css 3.0 attribute? could i implement this in css 2.1?

Comment: You don't need that `display` property. Try without it... :)